# Concept of channel, port and line in labview programming

Tags: labview

I am starting to learn the labview programming from the code written by someone else long time ago. Here I saw IO channel, line and port, I guess their meaning by reading code but I am looking someone to clarify that for me. To my understanding, IO channel is refer to analogy input/output port, port refer to 8-bit, 16-bit or 32-bit digital input/output pins, each bit (pin) is called a line. Is that correct?

Comment: This is very dependent to the hardware it's connected to.

Comment: Your assessment is generally true for NI hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using NI-DAQmx, which is the up-to-date software interface for programming NI's data acquisition hardware, the explanation of this terminology can be found [here](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370466W-01/TOC8.htm). The complete help for DAQmx is [here](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370466W-01/).

If you're looking at very old code which was written for very old hardware it's possible it might be what NI now call 'Traditional DAQ' rather than DAQmx, but I think the terminology is the same. I think Traditional DAQ VI's will have names starting with 'DAQ' or 'NI-DAQ' rather than 'DAQmx'.